# How to ETIMEDOUT with nock and request library

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

How to force ETIMEDOUT with `nock` (https://github.com/node-nock/nock) and `request`?
 I tried following, where `nock` will delay response for 8000 milliseconds while timeout for request will be set to 5000 milliseconds, so i would expect to see `ETIMEDOUT` but that is not the case. Code will return `then block should not execute:  Hello from Google!`

mocha test/force-req-timeout.test.js --timeout=10000

```
'use strict'

const expect = require('chai').expect
const nock = require('nock')
const rp = require('request-promise')

describe('force request timeout with nock', () => {
  it('should return ETIMEDOUT', (done) => {

    nock('http://www.google.com')
    .get('/')
    .delay(8000)
    .reply(200, 'Hello from Google!')

    rp({
      url: 'http://www.google.com',
      timeout: 5000
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('then block should not execute: ', data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      expect(err.cause.code).to.equal('ETIMEDOUT')
      return done()
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

In the end i solved it with:

```
nock('http://www.google.com')
  .get('/')
  .replyWithError({code: 'ETIMEDOUT'})
```

Which looks clean, it does not involve `delay` and stuff, and as it seems to me
it is enough to simulate `ETIMEDOUT` having in mind that im using
`request-promise` lib where im checking for `ETIMEDOUT` like:
`if (err.error && err.error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT')`

Comment: There are two type of timeouts, ETIMEDOUT and ESOCKETTIMEDOUT. To make it more realistic while waiting for the Nock team to have it fixed, add connect:true or connect:false respectively.